# Setting an Active Cell Value to a variable in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to run a macro that will open a workbook, complete a series of procedures on it, save it, Close it.  Then in the Macro workbook it will move down one row and use that cells value as the filename to open the next workbook.

The issue I am having is how do I get VBA to store a cells value as a variable:

The basics of the macro would look like this:

```
Dim Num as Long
Num = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim Name as String
Name = ?

Workbooks.Open Filename:="N:\PricingAudit\FY16 Price Increase\Raw DBF Files\TreatmentFiles\" + Name

...
...

Workbooks(Name).Close
...
```

Any help would be greatly. Appreciated in this:

Thanks in advance

Comment: Name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "A").Value. Change (1, "A") to where is your cell location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say in the worksheet we have:

[image]

Then here is one method:

```
Sub Dural()
    Dim MyName As String
    MyName = Range("A1").Text
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\TestFolder\" & MyName
    Set wbfirst = ActiveWorkbook
    '.......
    '.......
    '.......
    wbfirst.Close
End Sub
```

NOTE:

1. the string variable does not replicate a known property *(Name)*
2. we **close** using an Object rather than "by name"
3. we use **&** rather than **+**